# The computation of rotation matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

I got stuck on this quick computation which involve a rotation matrix.

Suppose $R\in \mathbb R^{N\times N}$ is a rotation matrix, i.e., $|R|=1$ and $RR^T=I$. Let us write $R=(R_{ij})$, $1\leq i,j\leq N$. Now I want to conclude that 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^N a^k R_{ik}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^N R_{ji}b_j\right)\right] =\sum_{i=1}^N a^i b_i$$
where $a$, $b\in \mathbb R^N$.

It should be true from my book but I can not justify it. Any help is really welcome!!

Comment: rotation matrice keeps the length same(isometric), therefore the inner product is also invariant.

Comment: Why the superscripts ?

Comment: @abel what do you mean by inner product is invariant?

Comment: @YvesDaoust ah no special reasons, just follow the book. For $a$ and $b$ it has different background meanings.

Comment: i mean $\langle Ra, Rb \rangle = \langle a,b \rangle$

Comment: @abel Thank you! understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $R R^T = R^T R = I$, you have $(Ra)^T (Rb) = a^T R^T R b = a^T b$.